# Instrumental Variable - High correlation between exogenous and fitted endogenous variable - sign flip

Tags: causality, instrumental-variables

I have a question about IV regression with 1 endogenous (`END`) and 1 exogenous (`EX`)variable. Endogenous and exogenous variables are moderately correlated (.21). The instrument (`INS`) is correlated with the endogenous variable with .09.
After the first stage, the correlation between exogenous variable (`EX`) and fitted endogenous variable (`END_hat`) is quite strong (~.91).

Therefore (I suppose?!), the results of the IV regression are somewhat strange as the sign of the exogenous variable flips (becomes negative).

My question is: What can be done in cases like this? Just putting more exogenous variables cannot be a solution, I guess?

To better understand the question, here a simulation in R:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(faux)
library(psych)
library(ivreg)

set.seed(1)

df <- rnorm_multi(n = 9000,
                  mu = c(0, 13, 2.3, 0),
                  sd = c(0.9, 2.5, 0.7, 0.9),
                  r = c(0.4, 0.13, 0.21, 0.09, 0.21, -0.01),
                  varnames = c("Y","END","INS","EX"),
                  empirical = TRUE)

describe(df)
cor(df)

first_stage <- lm(formula = "END ~ INS + EX",
                   data = df)
summary(first_stage)

END_hat <- fitted(first_stage)
df <- cbind(df, END_hat)
cor(df) # very high correlation between EX and fitted END (END_hat)

second_stage <- lm(formula = "Y ~  END_hat + EX",
                   data = df)
summary(second_stage) # EX effect negative

iv_model <- ivreg(formula = "Y ~ END + EX | INS + EX",
        data = df) 
summary(iv_model) # EX effect negative
```

I added a diagram showing the relationships between the variables.

- Y = Outcome
- END = Endogenous variable
- EX = Exogenous covariate
- INS = Instrument for END

[image]

**EDIT:**
With the "flipping sign" I mean that the sign of the effect of EX flips compared to a normal OLS with Y as the outcome and END and EX as the predictors.

I think it's because of the high correlation of END_hat and EX which in turn can be explained by the relatively high correlation between EX and END compared to the lower correlation between INS and END. As the correlation between INS and END becomes larger (the instrument becomes stronger), the correlation between EX and END_hat decreases and the sign of EX in the IV regression becomes positive (as in the OLS case).

So, I think this is a problem of a relatively weak instrument (Nevertheless, the F statistic is > 10) and a quite strong correlation between EX and END. However, I am not sure how to tackle this issue. One possible solution would be to add more exogenous variables so that EX looses some weight in the prediction of END in the first stage. However, this approach seems weird/arbitrary to me.

Comment: Can you please provide a causal diagram (directed acyclic graph) illustrating the relationships among your variables `END, INS, EX,` and `Y`?

Comment: I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You mean the sign "flip" between the first and second stage? I would not see why we would expect these two signs to agree - in the first, we estimate the partial correlation of the exogenous with the endogenous, while in the second, it is the partial correlation with the dependent after controlling for the (instrumented) endogenous. Can you maybe elaborate why you are surprised?

Comment: Should there be an arrow from `EX` to `END`? Or vice versa? Otherwise, how would `END` be endogenous? Or why would you need an instrument? You need an instrument if there is a confounding variable (variable that sets up a backdoor path). But, as drawn, you don't have any backdoor paths, and hence no need to use an instrument or any other identification mechanism like backdoor or frontdoor adjustment.

Comment: Sorry, I left out the error term which would be correlated with `END`.

Comment: re your edit: I get positive coefficients for END for both IV and standard OLS (which is not in your code, so I added `ols <- lm(formula = "Y ~ END + EX", data = df);  summary(ols)`

Comment: thx, this was a typo. It is the sign of the effect of EX that differs between IV and OLS.

Comment: Can you please update the DAG? The arrow directions are absolutely essential. Correlations alone are completely inadequate to determine what needs to be done: you must know the directions of the causality.